# How to save a large file (above 15 MB) in MySQL using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and MySQL.

I have created a table with field `File_Content` of type `longblob`.

When I try to save a file of size 15MB, I ger a fatal error like as :

```
**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 45464451 bytes)**
```

I found some instructions on how to set `max_allowed_packet`, but I am still unaware on how I can set it in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

The htaccess version would be something like this:

```
php_value max_allowed_packet "100M"
```